# Regex ot extract multiple substrings

Tags: regex

Example string containing one or more variables comma separated: TR.ASDASD, TU.IOHOUFHAF, XP.FWEFRWE .....

I need to use Regex to extract the characters before the . and end up with a string like this: TR, TU, XP

thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Does the first part allways have 2 characters? Can there also be strings like `AA.BBB.CCC`, or just `AA`?

Comment: Please clearly mention what you have tried and what is the issue. Dont ask us to work on something directly..

Comment: Also, are you sure you need regex? A simple split around `.` and retrieving the first part would certainly be more efficient if it is a possibility.

Comment: The first part before the . could have 1-5 characters, the second part could have any number of characters.

Comment: I have not got very farwith this as i am very new to Regex - I dont normally need it but seems the only option I have for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex works for what you need:

```
\..+?(?=,|$)
```

You need to substitute with nothing (an empty string).

This matches a `.`, then anything up to a comma or string end.

Example of it working: https://regex101.com/r/cV5hS2/1